# Habilitar compresion GZIP en el .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

He habilitado la compresión GZIP a través de el archivo `.htaccess`. Todo esta bien cuando hago las pruebas con `gtmetrix` a la [pagina de inicio](http://myonline.menu/mobilem) pero cuando hago las pruebas a otras de las secciones opciones como [esta](http://myonline.menu/mobilem/fr/home) me dice que no esta activa la compresión.

Archivo .htaccess

```
## COMPRESSING GZIP##
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
## COMPRESSING GZIP##

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /mobile/
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


    RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar solo hay que agregarle la siguiente linea de código al .htaccess
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]`
Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema

Comment: Hola DevMaster732 que bueno que solucionaste tu problema. Puedes dejar la solución como respuesta y no solo como comentario para que otro que tiene el mismo problema y vea tu respuesta pueda votar por ella.

Comment: @DevMaster732 puedes crear la respuesta con la solución que aplicaste, así la pregunta podrá marcarse cómo resuelta.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
```

Comment: Buenas @Aspoky, intenta extender mas tu respuesta explicando que hace lo que estás poniendo como solución al problema, ya que sinó no tendrá el formato que se busca y acabará eliminandose.

Comment: Hola Aspoky. Como te dice @Marc has de explicar más. Mira [answer] para guiarte en la mejora. Un saludo

Comment: en realidad no se lo que hace, pero si ayuda a solucionarlo, si lo supiera pondría más información